# Non-negative definite self adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

Let $G$ be a non-negative definite self adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$. I want to show that for all $f,g\in H$ we have $$(Gf,h)^2\leq (Gf,f)(Gh,h).$$ Can anyone help?

Comment: Case 1: suppose $(Gh,h) = 0$.  Case 2: if $(Gh,h) \neq 0$, then we can divide by $(Gh,h)$ and so we can use the proof of the [Cauchy Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#First_proof), noting that $\langle f,h\rangle := (Gf,h)$ "acts like an inner product".

Comment: Another approach here is to consider the positive definite map that $G$ induces on the quotient space $H/\ker G$

Comment: ah ok I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This holds whether $G$ is non-negative definite or non-negative semi-definite. For example, if it is non-negative semi-definite, then the following defines an inner product for every $\epsilon > 0$.
$$
                   \langle f,g \rangle_{\epsilon} = (Gf,g)+\epsilon (f,g)
$$
Consequently, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds:
$$
                     |\langle f,g\rangle_{\epsilon}|^2\le \langle f,f\rangle_{\epsilon}\langle g,g\rangle_{\epsilon}
$$
Letting $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ gives
$$
              |(Gf,g)|^2 \le (Gf,f)(Gg,g).
$$